# Pre-Selection Test

Tags: interviewing

I was pre-selected during a phone interview, and I did subsequently receive a test online.

I don't know nothing about some topics.

Should I provide random answers, or should I leave the answers blank?

For the sake of accuracy, merely.

Comment: Does it tell you how the test is marked - would you be penalised for wrong answers? Or are they assuming you'll have time to look up the answers you don't know?

Comment: Does the test form allow you to leave answers blank? Is there a "don't know" choice available?  Some poorly designed questionnaires will insist you answer everything but not provide a "don't know" option.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how the test is evaluated; automatically for a quick filtering of candidates or by another person as a starting point for an interview.

In the first case, I would answer all questions including the ones where I have no idea. I'm assuming there is some cut-off score that needs to be reached to proceed further in the hiring process.

However, if you are further along in the process and the test will be evaluated by humans, I would answer questions to the best of my ability including making educated guesses - but leave the questions blank where I really have absolutely no idea.

In a Danish context at least, it would generally seem more trustworthy to demonstrate your knowledge as well as your limitations.

Comment: Well, the test include some stuff I don't have in my CV. So, I felt it was bad to try to guess, or to look for answers online. I prefer to reflect what I master ... I just don't want them to be offended. That's all.

Comment: Your approach is sound. You cannot be expected to have knowledge you do not claim to have. In those situations, employers can only evaluate what you then do - and not attempting to fake anything seems the best option

Answer (score 1):

While I understand that you do not wish to provide answers to questions outside what you have listed on your CV, I suspect that you may be selling yourself short in the application process.

No one can know everything about a given position and often duties are expanded.  As someone who is hiring I would expect a applicant faced with something new or unfamiliar to at least attempt to research the answer and provide what information they can.

When in doubt you can always contact the person who sent you the test and ask if they would like answers to all the questions, even the ones outside of your experience.

Good Luck.